# C# multiplying a method containing an instance of Random.next

Tags: c#, methods, random

I'm running this class and method

```
public class DiceRoll
{
    static Random _r =new Random();

    public int Random6()
    {
        int n = _r.Next(1, 7);
        return n;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use it inside an if statement in another class like so:

```
if (input == "d6")
{
    int dice = diceRoll.Random6();
    Console.WriteLine(dice);
}
```

my question is this. If I call `diceRoll.Random6();` with a multiplier like this `diceRoll.Random6() * 2;` Is it creating two random numbers and adding them or is it just taking one and multiplying it by two?

I think it's probably the latter but I just wanted to check before I got into convoluted programming.

If it is the latter is there a way to make my program call multiple instances of `Random6` without going `diceRoll.Random6() + diceRoll.Random6();` That works ok for doing it twice but if I want to do it four or six times it'll become inelegant.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could return an array of numbers from your Random6 method, and pass in the number required as a parameter. Or call the method from within a loop

Comment: How is it inelegant?...

Comment: If you want to do it four or six times it might be time to start using a loop.

Comment: If I have to go `diceRoll.Random6() + diceRoll.Random6() + diceRoll.Random6() + diceRoll.Random6() + diceRoll.Random6() + diceRoll.Random6();` it seems like there should be a better way. That to me is enelegant

Comment: based on general consensus I shal try it with a loop

Comment: A note to readers: [Rolling 2d6 actually has a probability curve](http://anydice.com/program/20) which means numbers in the middle of the range are much more likely to occur than numbers either end. This applies to any Xd6 roll where X > 1. Merely randomly picking a number between 2 and 12 inclusive is not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the method from within a loop

```
int result = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      result += Random6();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It just generates 1 random number then multiplies it by 2

you can just do it in a loop, or if you want to be fancy

```
var sum = Enumerable.Range(1, 6).Sum(x => diceRoll.Random6())
```

which you might want to break down into...

```
var rolls = Enumerable.Range(1, 6).Select(x => diceRoll.Random6()).ToList();
var sumOfRolls = rolls.Sum();
```

that way you have the sum and a list of each individual roll.

Comment: Just as I thought. Is there an elegant way to get it two call the method twice

Comment: How about `Enumerable.Range(1, 2).Select(x => diceRoll.Random6()).Sum()`

Or you could stop trying to be elegant and call the method twice, or use a loop for a variable number of calls.

Comment: heh, same thing I just put in my answer :)

Comment: while i can appreciate LINQ, i don't think this user is particularly ready for linq expressions. he is better off doing a simple for loop.

Comment: possibly, I think the sooner you get into linq the better, one of the key things to effective linq use is to stop thinking in terms of loops.  But everyone kind of finds their own winding path through programming :)

Comment: Yeah what Stan R. said is correct. I don't even know what LINQ is. Though I am now going to google it to find out.

Comment: @AmazingMrBrock its worth learning, once you get your head around it, many problems can be solved in nice simple ways.  Less things to go wrong as well, which creates for more robust code.